# How to implement react native wallet connect V1 and V2 using wallet connect?

Tags: react, walletconnect

I've already implemented react native wallet V2, but I can't implement react native wallet V1. Could anyone kindly explain about react native wallet(Not Dapp) V1?
Please let me know source code URL OR documentation for it.